# I have one Datepicker and because of users may write invalid characters to textbox, i want to have datepicker validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datepicker

```
  when I enter 123456 in date textbox then not validating.
```

it should validate when I enter wrong input like(123456) or any string .(ddsfgdfddf)
Need validation in date field
when we type 123456 in date textbox validation should occur
Now you can browse privately, and other people who use this device won’t see your activity. However, downloads and bookmarks will be saved. Learn more

```
        @section Scripts {


                       @Scripts.Render("~/application/Report")

            <script type="text/javascript">


                $(document).ready(function () {





                    Report.Initialize();
                    Report.validatationForDateFromAndDateTo("dateFrom", "dateTo");
                    $("#pageOrientation").val("use landscape");
                });
            </script>
        }
    [enter image description here][1]
    validatationForDateFromAndDateTo: function (dateFromId, dateToId) {

                    $("#" + dateFromId + ", #" + dateToId).on("change", function () 
        {
                        debugger;
                        var areDatesPresent = true;
            var startDateText = $("#" + dateFromId).val();
                        var leavingDateText = $("#" + dateToId).val();
                        var startDateTextLenght =$("#" + dateFromId).val().length;

                        if (startDateText == "") {
                            areDatesPresent = false;
                            Base.setResetErrorMessage('DateFromError', "Date from is required.", true);
                        }
                        else { Base.setResetErrorMessage('DateFromError', "", false); }

                        if (leavingDateText == "") {
                            areDatesPresent = false;
                            Base.setResetErrorMessage('DateToError', "Date to is required.", true);
                        }
                        else { Base.setResetErrorMessage('DateToError', "", false); }
             if (areDatesPresent) {
                            var startDate = new Date(startDateText);
                            var leavingDate = new Date(leavingDateText);

                            if (leavingDate < startDate || $(this).val() == "") {
                                Base.setResetErrorMessage('DateFromError', "Date from must be less than Date to.", true);
                                Base.setResetErrorMessage('DateToError', "Date to must be greater than Date from.", true);
                                $("#GetReport").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                            }
                            else {
                                Base.setResetErrorMessage('DateFromError', "", false);
                                Base.setResetErrorMessage('DateToError', "", false);
                                $("#GetReport").attr("disabled", false);
                            }
                        }
            else {
                            $("#GetReport").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                        }



            View:

            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                                    <div class="input-group date">
                                                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
                                                        <input type="text" id="dateFrom" name="dateFrom" class="form-control"  value="@dateFrom.ToString(Consts.DateFormats.DateOnly) ">
                                                    </div>
                                                    @Html.ValidationMessage("DateFromError")
                                                    [enter image description here][1]
                                                </div>
                enter code here

              [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuVfa.png


        <div class="input-group date">
                                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
                                                    <input type="datetime" id="dateTo" name="dateTo" class="form-control"  value="@dateTo.ToString(Consts.DateFormats.DateOnly)">
                                                </div>
                                                @Html.ValidationMessage("DateToError")

                                            </div>**strong text**



    View :

     <div class="col-sm-12">
                                                    <div class="input-group date">
                                                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
                                                        <input type="text" id="dateFrom" name="dateFrom" class="form-control"  value="@dateFrom.ToString(Consts.DateFormats.DateOnly) ">
                                                    </div>
                                                    @Html.ValidationMessage("DateFromError")
                                                    [enter image description here][1]
                                                </div>
                enter code here

              [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuVfa.png


        <div class="input-group date">
                                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
                                                    <input type="datetime" id="dateTo" name="dateTo" class="form-control"  value="@dateTo.ToString(Consts.DateFormats.DateOnly)">
                                                </div>
                                                @Html.ValidationMessage("DateToError")

                                            </div>

      [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKt4y.png
```

Comment: You may want to revise your question, move the image to an appropriate place (if it is really necessary to understanding your question) and to provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: i want just when enter 123456 or any fdfsfsfsfsf then it validate date is not valid..

Comment: plz help me i need it

Comment: "plz help me i nnedit.." is not going to magically make us want to sift throught that badly-formatted and invalid code. Please, help us helping you. Rules on this site are not arbitrary, they are designed to make it easier for you to obtain an answer.

Comment: You need to but yourself a good book or go to the MVC site ans work through the tutorials to learn some fundamental basics. In particular how to use `HtmlHelper` helper methods as bind to a model and use validation attributes for client and server side validation (none of your scripts will required because its all down automatically!)

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use [input type=date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date) and let the browser handle the formatting of the field

```
<input id="date" type="date">
```

Comment: when i change the type then in the textbox datepicker dd-mm-yy is showing]'

Comment: It depends on the browser how it handles a type=date field.

Comment: when i enter 123456 then it shows date from should be greter than date to..but it should give invalid date..

Comment: you can set min/max attribute on `type="date"`s too